# QDialogButtonBox::accepted() is protected

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I want to write my custom input dialog. I wrote following lines to handle click on OK/Cancel:

```
connect(buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::accepted,this, &MyCustomDialog::accept);
```

I got this error on compile:

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qdialogbuttonbox.h:147:10: error: 'void QDialogButtonBox::accepted()' is protected
     void accepted();
```

There isn't any public signal in `QDialogButtonBox`.

Comment: You're using the new (Qt5) syntax for `connect`, but your Qt installation appears to be Qt4

Comment: I saw that on Qt website. There isn't any note about Qt version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about `QDialogButtonBox`. It is about your `Qt` version. You are using `Qt5` syntax for singal-slot while you have `Qt4`. Use this:

```
connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()),this, SLOT(accept()));
```

`accepted` is a `Q_SIGNALS` which is `protected` in `Qt4`, so you can't use that syntax.